# Grouping an array elements in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, group-by

How can I group the following array if the subtraction of elements is less than 2?

```
var myarr = [1.7, 2, 1.4, 6, 7, 14, 15, 21,31,33.2,33.5]
```

And I want to have this result:

```
 var myarr = [[1.7, 2, 1.4], [6, 7], [14, 15], [21],[31,33.2,33.5]]
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: yes, But it failed and I don't know how to use lodash groupBy for this array.

Comment: Post your attempt.  Please read [ask] and then how to create a [mcve]

Comment: Can you share this partial failed code?

Comment: Is the array already sorted?

Comment: @gurvinder372 `[1.7, 2, 1.4,` I guess no.

Comment: To People who give a negative grade, wasn't  the question clear enough?

Comment: @MaryamKoulaei Please mind the tone. Its not just about clarity. We are here to help fellow devs with their problems, not with their requirements. So unless you share your attempt, this is a requirement and not a problem statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the array, and add a new sub array to the accumulator if the delta between the current and previous numbers is greater or equal to 2 (or it's the 1st number). Push the current number to the last array:

```js
var myarr = [1.7, 2, 1.4, 6, 7, 14, 15, 21,31,33.2,33.5]

var result = myarr.reduce(function(r, n, i, arr) {
  if(i === 0 || Math.abs(n - arr[i - 1]) >= 2) r.push([])
  
  r[r.length - 1].push(n)

  return r
}, []);

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use the absolute value of the difference for checking with the wanted delta for inserting a new array in the result set, because the order of the values is not strictly ascending.

```js
var array = [1.7, 2, 1.4, 6, 7, 14, 15, 21, 31, 33.2, 33.5],
    delta = 2,
    grouped = array.reduce(function (r, v, i, a) {
        if (!i || Math.abs(a[i - 1] - v) > delta) {
            r.push([]);
        }
        r[r.length -1].push(v);
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```